# Xcode doesn't get the libGoogleAdMobAds.a framework?

Tags: ios, linker, admob

I'm trying to add AdMobs to my app but it continues giving me this error

> linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

i've added all the framework and set "other liker flag" to -ObjC
but i think xcode didn't get this libGoogleAdMobAds.a framework, it appears in the list but it seems it can't read.
i've tried to add it from the "build phase" > "+" > "add other" but nothing changed..

what can i do?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is usually a caching error. Try any and all of the following:

- Usually just "unticking" and "ticking" the target on the File Inspector (<kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>) does it for me.

Alternatively:

- Remove the library

  - From your project
  - From the build phases
  - From library search paths
- Clean
- Add the library by dragging it into your project
- Ensure it is "ticked" to be added to your target
- Ensure it's included in your library search paths
- Ensure it's been added to your build phases.